# When do we get "'NaN' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value" in SQLException?

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, stripes

I have added the following code in my JSP and getting some exception on saving entity to db.

```
 $('.validateWeight').click(function(event) {
var id = event.target.id;
var value;
$("#saveValue").val("");
if(id == "saveAndContinue"){
   var el = document.getElementById('saveValue');
   el.value = 1;
   //<c:set var="saveValue" scope="page" value="1"/>;
}else if(id=="saveAndClose"){
   var el = document.getElementById('saveValue');
   el.value = 2;
   //<c:set var="saveValue" scope="page" value="2"/>;
}
```

and

and in my **Java Action Class**, I have added the getter and setter

I am getting values set to 1 and 2 in needed cases but when saving the entity I do not how and from where '`NAN`' value is coming and I am getting issues with save call.

Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: Hibernate operation: could not update: [com.hk.domain.inventory.GrnLineItem#100]; SQL [update person set age=?, no_of_children=?, address_line_1=?, address_line_2=?, mrp=?, state=?, city=?, pincode=?, weight=? where id=?]; 'NaN' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: 'NaN' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value
org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:107)
org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.flush(HibernateTemplate.java:881)
com.hk.impl.dao.BaseDaoImpl.resetHibernateAfterWrite(BaseDaoImpl.java:247)
```

and

```
java.sql.SQLException: 'NaN' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setDouble(PreparedStatement.java:3572)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setDouble(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:129)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setDouble(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:129)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setDouble(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:129)
org.hibernate.type.DoubleType.set(DoubleType.java:60)
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:154)
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:131)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2025)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2399)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2335)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2635)
org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:115)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:168)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$28.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:883)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.flush(HibernateTemplate.java:881)
com.hk.impl.dao.BaseDaoImpl.resetHibernateAfterWrite(BaseDaoImpl.java:247)
com.hk.impl.dao.BaseDaoImpl.save(BaseDaoImpl.java:237)
```

Comment: when you put it in `el.value` it turns to `String`. you need to find the way to send it to DB not from `input`

Comment: it means the sql column is of type of integer and the value you are trying to save is of type string.

Comment: but I am using the "saveValue" field in an if-else clause. The vale has not any relation with db or any other entity?

Comment: Can you please share the Pojo/Entity and the table schema in to which you are saving the record.

Comment: I got the issue fixed. There was a calculation which would set a field to infinity and hence was not being saved. Was more of confused with Jsp's NAN and this NAN (one mentioned in sql exception). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your javascript to use Jquery

```
$('.validateWeight').click(function(event) {
   var id = event.target.id;

   $("#saveValue").val("");
   if (id == "saveAndContinue")
      $("#saveValue").val(1);
   else if (id == "saveAndClose")
      $("#saveValue").val(2);
}
```

You have to take into account that if **id** isn't "saveAndContinue" or "saveAndClose", the value of the input with ID "saveValue" will be "", which is not numeric and will produce your NaN error.

In the other hand, you should check if in the server side you receive a String or a Integer, because you should pass to your Hibernate function an Integer.